# I have vs I have one

Tags: grammar, meaning-in-context, sentence-construction

Suppose someone asks me "*Do you have any sister*? Which answer would be more appropriate?

> Yes. I have.

Or

> Yes. I have one.

If both one is correct then what is the difference between them?

Is the sentence "*Yes, I have a sister* "
uncommon?

Comment: @banuyayi - no native speaker would ask 'Do you have any sister?'. You would use the plural 'sisters' and where I live people would ask 'Do you have any brothers and sisters?'. Just asking about sisters might seem odd, especially if a man was asking.

Comment: It was an oversight. I apologise. Now I cannot edit the comment.

Comment: @banuyayi - you can copy it to your clipboard, delete it it, and past the edited text into a new comment.

Comment: "Do you have any sisters?", "Yes. I have.", "Yes. I have one.", "Yes. I have one sister.", "Yes. I have two.", "Yes. I have two sisters.", "Yes. I have three.", "Yes. Countless sisters I have.". Thank you @ Michael Harvey

Answer (score 1):

> "Do you have any sisters?"

The question must use the plural. If it uses the singular it is a mistake which I would politely overlook and assume the question used the plural.

Then "Yes" means "I have at least one sister", and "Yes, I have a sister" means "I have one sister".

I won't say "I have one sister", when I also have two sisters, even if it is technically true.

So the difference is that the second answer includes the number of sisters. THe first answer does not.